# Change Data Capture Using Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have few tables which are related as `A -> Left Join -> B -> Left join -> C`. Let's call `A` as the `driving table` and `B & C` as `"supporting"` tables. Each of these tables have a last_update_date column. My requirement is to identify the records that changed since the last processing date (available as a parameter) not only in the driving table but also if a change to any column occurs in the supporting table(s).

```
Table A  
------  
empid|salary|last_updt_dt  
123|20000|05/14/2019   

Table B  
-------  
empid|fname|lname|last_updt_date  
123|John|Taylor|05/16/2019  

Table C  
-------  
empid|address|last_updt_dt  
123|Maryland|05/17/2019
```

Assume,  = 05/10/2019

So, assuming executing job on Day 1 (05/20/2019) output should be:

```
empid|fname|lname|salary|address|last_exec_date  
-----------------------------------------------    
123|John|Taylor|20000|Maryland|05/20/2019
```

Now, let's assume that on Day 2 (05/21/2019), the address got changed from `Maryland` to `California`. So, on Day 2, the output table should look like:

```
empid|fname|lname|salary|address|last_exec_date  
-----------------------------------------------    
123|John|Taylor|20000|Maryland|05/20/2019 
123|John|Taylor|20000|California|05/21/2019 
561|Peter|Anderson|50000|Missouri|05/21/2019
```

The point to note is that on Day 2 a change in any "supporting table" (Table-C 'address' column in this case) triggered insertion of another record which was already processed earlier yesterday, but now with Updated value in address column. Also note, on Day 2 other inserts will happen as-is as regular inserts for any other qualifying record (if any) e.g. empid=561.

```
SELECT
A.empid, B.fname, B.lname, A.salary, C.address, current_date() as last_exec_date
from A
left outer join B
on A.empid = B.empid
left outer join B.empid = C.empid
where to_date(A.last_updt_dt, 'yyyyMMdd') > {last_exec_date}
OR to_date(A.last_updt_dt, 'yyyyMMdd') > {last_exec_date}
to_date(A.last_updt_dt, 'yyyyMMdd') > {last_exec_date}
```

My challenge is how to trigger and propagate any changes from any of the participating supporting tables, even when that change pertains to a record which had been processed and inserted to the target table earlier, so that a new record with the updated value shows in the target table.
In other word how can I trigger a record with a change from any of the other supporting (non-driver) tables

Comment: U find the question unclear: you supply SQL so that is not the issue. Are you looking for a CDC mechanism?

Comment: yes i'm looking for a CDC mechanism

Comment: Outside of Spark?

Comment: using spark-sql

Comment: the query you mean?